# Google maps and geospatial issues

Tags: google-maps, geospatial

I'm working on a couple of different websites/apps that have a common thread.  I need to be able to allow a user to login to my website/app and based on their location be able to see all of the widgets within a predefined range.

How do I efficiently find the widgets within the predefined range when their are like 15k of them?  And their could be a thousand or so users doing searches at the same time?  I'm kinda hoping google maps has some sort of cloud thingee happening that might let me cheat.  Dunno.  All I know is I don't have the funds to create my own data center to crunch location information.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on geospatial engines or something?  Again, I kinda see there's a problem I just have no clue what the answer would even look like.

Comment: 15000 rows is not a lot to a database like SQL if it's properly maintained

Comment: It's not so much the rows that worries as much as the processing involved in having to do 15000 comparisons.  Especially when probably 99% fall out of range.  Couple that with, hopefully, lots of users doing searches.  It could be bad :(

Comment: Doesn't the new version of SQL have geography built in? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx I know MongoDB does - what tenchnologies are you looking at?

Comment: Right now it'll probably be c# + MSSQL.  I'm using a hosting service so I'm not sure how much MSSQL I get access to.  I'm pretty sure I have to use the cpannel only - no MSSQL console like I do at work.

Comment: Okdoke, looks like Liath has the answer that works for me.  I had not seen SQL Servers Spatial data functions.  AFter breezing through some websites I feel this is the answer I was looking for - not sure how to give you credit on SO but here's some props for you anyway - thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadkey. It is used for the tiles but you can use it for spatial index. You can also use a bounding box but then it's not an index. I have wrote a php class hibert curve @ phpclasses.org.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the new [geography datatypes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) in MSSQL Server. There is inbuilt functionality to handle [distance between points](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) which allows you to find only the relevant 'widgets' at a DB level.

Here's an extract from the second link as an example:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);
```